# Angular 4 loading spinner causes 'Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content'

Tags: html, css, angular, optimization, pagespeed

I've just written a loading spinner for my application, a simple div that should show whenever angular hasn't yet kicked in, and it works really well, but Google's PageSpeed Insights now gives me an 81 and 91/100 respectively for 'Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content'.

If I remove the spinner it goes back to 100, and if i inline the spinner CSS it bumps up to 85 and 95. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my index.html and the css that is inlined:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <base href="/">
  <style>
    #loading_spin{
      background:url('assets/misc/loading.png') no-repeat;
      background-size:contain;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      position:fixed;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      margin-left: -50px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      animation: spin_load 2s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes spin_load{
      from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body id="corp">
   <master_page>
     <div id="loading_spin"></div> //this is the one causing the score
   </master_page>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<master-page></master_page>` tags are my `app.component.ts` selector:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'master_page',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way that I could bypass this and still get a full 100 score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By my knowledge there is no way to bypass it. The extra roundtrip google pagespeed is talking about is the image you are loading to display the spinner: `'assets/misc/loading.png'`. You can try to make this an inline base64 url, replace it with a similar inline svg, or make it yourself using css animations.

The eliminate render blocking css, is obviously your remote css to display the loader. This css is very tiny, and you can easily use it inline in the initial index.html request.

Note though that creating a perfect 100 pagespeed score with a full JavaScript/Client application is practically impossible. You could however look at server side rendering for angular. I don't have the appropriate knowledge there, but what I do know is that you can use this to pre compile your application on the server, which will give you a precompiled `index.html` with the loaded components.

Comment: Many thanks! I encoded the image in base64, included that as the `background:url` and that seemed to have done the trick, I'm back to 100 now.